# Suffering to create a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating an asset management system where said asset was assigned a control number.

This code consists of type of options the first one is
It starts with the letter `P` is capitalized, followed by a number ranging from 0-7, then a hyphen, then three or two uppercase letters, followed by a hyphen and ends with a 5 digit.

This regular expression

```
/^((P){1}[0-7]{1})-([A-Z]{2,3})-([0-9]{5})$/
```

has already been created and works correctly. My problem is with the second option which starts with `SOT`, then a hyphen, then three or two uppercase letters, followed by a hyphen and ends with a 5 digit.

My interpretation of this expression was

```
/^SOT-([A-Z]{2,3})-([0-9]{5})$/
```

But when I check that it is correct I get my own "pattern does not match" message and I have been looking for hours for the error. If you got as far as thanks for reading and helping me.

JS

```
    let $input=document.querySelector('#valor');
    let $input2=document.querySelector('#valor2');
    if (!$input.value.match(/^[0-9]{6,7}$/)) {
        $mensaje.textContent='Debe ser un número de 6 o 7 digitos';
        $mensaje.style.textAlign = 'center';
        $mensaje.style.width = '62%' 
        $mensaje.classList.remove('none');
        $mensaje.classList.add('is-active');
        $boton.disabled=true;
        $div.appendChild($mensaje);
    }else{
        $mensaje.classList.remove('is-active');
        $mensaje.classList.add('none');
        $boton.disabled=false;
    }
        if (!$input2.value.match(/^((P){1}[0-7]{1})-([A-Z]{2,3})-([0-9]{5})$/) || !$input2.value.match(/^SOT-([A-Z]{2,3})-([0-9]{5})$/)) {
        
        $mensaje.textContent='No cumple con el patrón';
        $mensaje.style.textAlign = 'center';
        $mensaje.style.width = '62%' 
        $mensaje.classList.remove('none');
        $mensaje.classList.add('is-active');
        $boton.disabled=true;
        $div.appendChild($mensaje);
            
    }else{
        $mensaje.classList.remove('is-active');
        $mensaje.classList.add('none');
        $boton.disabled=false;
    }
```

Comment: Try removing the start character (`^`), it looks like it works here: https://regexr.com/75gsv

Comment: isn't the [mcve] for this kind of problem is to.. have rules, sample input, expected output, and regex you have tried?

Comment: This question is about regular expressions. Why have you posted the HTML and several dozen lines of unrelated JavaScript? See [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for your comments/observations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is correct, but your test here is wrong:

```
if (!$input.value.match(/^((P){1}[0-7]{1})-([A-Z]{2,3})-([0-9]{5})$/) || !$input.value.match(/^SOT-([A-Z]{2,3})-([0-9]{5})$/)) {
```

You're using OR on two negatives. If a code matches the first regex it won't match the second and the expression is true, and vice versa.

Try this form:

```
if ($input.value.match(/^((P){1}[0-7]{1})-([A-Z]{2,3})-([0-9]{5})$/) ||
     $input.value.match(/^SOT-([A-Z]{2,3})-([0-9]{5})$/)) {
  // Value matches successfully
} else {
 // Value doesn't match
}
```

Alternatively, build both options into one regex, then there's only one test to do:

```
if ($input.value.match(/^(SOT|P[0-7])-([A-Z]{2,3})-([0-9]{5})$/)) {
   // Match
} else {
   // No match
}
```

This looks for `SOT` or `P0` to `P7` in the first group, then carries on as before.